# "Just another random thoughts/thought"

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct?

> Just another random thoughts.

or

> Just another random thought.

I'm writing a blog post about recent musings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safira's answer is correct if you want to keep the "*another* random thought" phrasing. However, your last line seems to imply you're looking for a way to incorporate *multiple* thoughts into the title of a blog post.

In this case, I would go for

> Just **some** random thoughts

This will keep the same feel and meaning of your original phrase, but use it in the plural.

Answer (score 2):

If you're taking it as a *noun* (something you think), it should be the second one:

> Just another random thought. [*without* **s**]

See, you use the word *another* which means it's *singular*, so there must be no **s** there. The first sentence [*with* **s**] is ***not*** a grammatical sentence.